# Product version timer job fails in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, timer-service

We have run the SharePoint configuration wizard both in SharePoint Application and WFE server (SharePoint 2016), since then we have started getting this error **"Product Version Job   Failed: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.. (Correlation=)"** occasionally, though it is not causing any issues in the SharePoint server. As part of the fix, we have cleared the SharePoint Config cache, then this job ran successfully for a couple of days - again it started coming occasionally not constantly.

1. What is the permanent fix for this?
2. If we ignore this error, will it cause any issues in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the Farm Admin service account a Local Admin -- don't do this, this is bad practice.
2. No.

Answer (score 0):

The function of Product Version Timer Job is putting the updated version information from the SharePoint Server on to the SharePoint Databases.

If the job doesn’t run, then there may be an issue on product version mismatch during certain server level operation. And it will not impact the update of SharePoint Production.

Reference:
[Product version job is failing in one server](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4a109bc7-41d4-4057-881b-4d2bc43cdd11/product-version-job-is-failing-in-one-server?forum=sharepointgeneral)